# XCode Instruments - Can't modify launch configuration for a profiling a process

Tags: xcode, profiling, instruments

I'm trying to profile a provider on my iPhone, however instruments won't allow me to modify the launch configuration in instruments. The icon is simply not there anymore.

**How It Should Look**

[image: How It Should Look]

**How Mine Looks**

[image]

I don't understand why the buttons are different. Where did it go?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I figured it out. It's been moved to the menu strip.

[image: Found It]